# copy recursively skipping directories with specific name

Tags: directory, cp, recursive

I have a directory with ~100 Gb. I need to copy this directory to other place skipping specific folders (there is a lot of them). The following is a wrong code to demonstrate my needs.

```
$ cp -r ~/directory_to_copy /path/to/copy --skip=foo --skip=bar
```

There is an example of result this command. Original directory tree is

```
~/directory_to_copy
  aaa
    foo
    doo
      bar
  bbb
    ccc
      ddd
        bar
      eee
```

Copied tree is

```
/path/to/copy/
  aaa
    doo
  bbb
    ccc
      ddd
      eee
```

How to write command for my purposes?

Comment: Do you have access to GNU tar?

Answer (score 10):

You want `rsync`:

```
rsync -va --exclude=foo --exclude=bar ~/directory_to_copy /path/to/copy
```

`--exclude` is used to exclude unwanted files or directories.

`-v` makes rsync verbose  (optional).

`-a` tells rsync to copy recursively and preserve file attributes.  This is optional but, if you don't use `-a`, you likely want to use `-r` to copy recursively.

For more complex requirements, both exclude and include options can be specified.  It is even possible to change the exclude/include settings from one directory to another by specifying the `-F` option and placing `.rsync-filter` files in various locations in the source directory hierarchy.  `man rsync` has details.

Comment: Actually, `-a` has the same effect as a bunch of other flags, one of which is `-r`(`--recursive`) which is *not* optional here.

Comment: @MatthiasUrlichs Good point.  Answer updated with info on `-r`.

Comment: you can upvote comments, you know ;-)

Answer (score 1):

you can use `find` for that

```
find -depth ! -wholename '*foo*' ! -wholename '*bar*' -exec cp --parents '{}' /target/dir/ \;
```

note that you will a) need `-depth` to make sure you first find the directories that need to be omitted and b) use the `--parents` option to `cp` to create the full path while copying.

This will however also skip empty folders as `-r` in `cp` cannot be used as then ALL filed would be copied once find comes to ./firstDIR .

Comment: Why not just `path`, `wholename` is less portable too..

Comment: might as well work, the `!` could also be avoided with `-prune` like in `... -path '*foo*' -o -path '*bar*' -prune -o -exec ... `